# SQL update join max

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my work which is not working

```
UPDATE
    TableA
SET
    A_Price = B_Price
FROM
    TableA
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT B_Name, max(B_Price)
            FROM TableB
            GROUP BY B_Name
        )
        ON A_Name = B_Name
WHERE
    ISNULL(RTRIM(A_Price),'')=''
```

What I want to do is

Some of A_Price is null or empty,
So I try to put B_Price into A_Price
I can only join two table by A_Name and B_Name
but here, there are many B_Price for B_Name
(1 name but many different prices)
So I want to insert the max price of B_Price into A_Price

anyone can help me please?

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong and also show some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine, except that you need to `SET` to the max price:

```
UPDATE a
SET A_Price = b.max_price
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT B_Name, MAX(B_Price) AS max_price
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY B_Name
) b
    ON a.A_Name = b.B_Name
WHERE
    COALESCE(REPLACE(a.A_Price, ' ', ''), '') = '';
```